# Android Bluetooth 4.0 Development

Tags: android, bluetooth

Has anyone done Bluetooth BLE development for android before? Currently, from what I researched, HTC and Samsung does provide APIs for their flagship devices.

HTC:http://www.htcdev.com/devcenter/opensense-sdk/bluetooth-low-energy

Samsung:http://developer.samsung.com/ble

Do these APIs usually depends on the Bluetooth hardware on the phone? For example from Atheros, Broadcom, etc.

From my experience in Bluetooth 2.0 development for example using the BlueCove API (http://bluecove.org/) It isn't hardware dependent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edit**: This answer is outdated, and since Android 4.3 (release date 24 July 2013), Android supports [Bluetooth LE](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/bluetooth-le.html).

---

Android does not have support for BLE hence different vendors have there own solutions. These solutions differ in design and implementation though the actual HCI(Hot controller interface) command to BT chip would be same which would not be exposed to the application developer.

FW API's exposed would not be dependent on the bluetooth hardware but middleware implementation have differ depending on the BLE h/w, hope it answers all your queries

Comment: Yeah, so I guess I can't use an API from HTC and put it to a Samsung phone then.

Comment: I don't think so.. can confirm the same in Samsung SDK for particular API

Comment: @user1157751 If com.samsung.android.sdk.bt.gatt is not shipped on your android device, you'll get a ClassNotFoundException. As simple as that. See https://developers.google.com/events/io/sessions/326240948 for the official Android BLE API that comes with 4.3